# What was being plotted at WWDC 2003?

Tags: plotting, fractals

At the [WWDC 2003 keynote](https://youtu.be/50AvChzTJ1k), Theodore Gray took the stage, along with Phill Schiller, and demoed Mathematica 5, comparing performance on G5 and Xeon processors.

[image]

In the presentation, a 40-step fractal battle is conducted and  I'd like to recreate this on my new Macbook. So I was wondering what function is being used to make the `DensityPlots` (if that's what they are)?

[image]

Comment: You don't, by chance, have any more pixels, do you?

Comment: I looked but the best YouTube video is only 480p and the text is unreadable

Comment: Looks like it computing some high order polynomial roots

Comment: @jasonb ok I added a gif of the screen capture...

Comment: From Michael Trott: "I darkly remember making something for Theo. But I don't think I have it anymore."

Comment: @JasonB. Doesn’t have to be the exact same

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that would be `ListDensityPlot`.

Some example code:

```
SqrtFractalSetup[{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, n_] := 
     With[{xminn = N[xmin], yminn = N[ymin], 
             xstep = N[(xmax - xmin)/n], ystep = N[(ymax - ymin)/n]}, 
       re0 = Table[r, {r, xminn, xmax, xstep}, {i, yminn, ymax, ystep}]; 
       im0 = Table[i, {r, xminn, xmax, xstep}, {i, yminn, ymax, ystep}]];

SqrtFractalDraw[c_, {xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}, steps_] := 
     Module[{quadrant}, {re, im} = {re0, im0}; 
        Do[{re, im} = {(c - Sqrt[Abs[re]] + Sqrt[Abs[im]])^2, 
                (1 - Sqrt[Abs[im]] - Sqrt[Abs[re]])^2}; , {steps}]; 
        quadrant = Abs[re + I*im]; 
        ListDensityPlot[quadrant, Mesh -> False, ColorFunction -> Hue, PlotRange -> All]]; 

SqrtFractalSetup[{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, 400]; 

Animate[SqrtFractalDraw[
  N[0.6 + 0.6*Cos[c] + (0.25 + 0.25*Sin[c])*I], {-1, 1}, {-1, 1}, 7], 
    {c, (2*Pi)/9, 2*Pi - (2*Pi)/9, (2*Pi)/36}]
```

[image]

and here is a related [video](https://www.youtube.com/embed/7TbnQbXSnC8?start=3452) from WWDC 2003:

[image]

Comment: Any words on the provenance of this awesome answer?